# Count Records X of Y across Records on Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a Form with fields StudentID, StartDate, TxDate (Treatment Date) among c.60 other fields.
There is a Go To Student drop-down box in the Form's Header that establishes a subset for the StudentID selected records only when a particular StudentID is selected from the drop-down.

There are buttons to click to First, Previous, Next, Last

I want to show on the Form, as you click First, Previous, Next, or Last, and go to the Next record, the number record for that individual StudentID.  That is, if the Student had 6 records, it would display 1 of 6 for their first record, 2 of 6 for the Next, 3 of 6 for the Next....

I've tried things like DCount('RecordNo","Depression Form Query","Student") which counts all the records in the Data Table, not just the individual StudentID's.

I used an Autonumber in the Students Table but it generates a number equivalent to the StudentID being the 3rd Student entered, not a count of their Treatment Dates.

I've tried various loopings I've found on the net but they do not count across records for the same Student.

I made an X of Y Report which I then dragged and dropped into the Form.  It generates the correct Y (6) but an incorrect X.

[[image]]

The Depression Form Query is based on the Students Table and the Depression Table.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html.

Comment: Please understand, I am counting across Forms (records), not within the same record.  StudentID = 8131999, Form's Record No = 356 (count would be "1"), clicking the Next button programmed by me on my Form takes me to another instance for StudentID 8131999, Form's Record No = 461 (count would be "2"), clicking the Next button programmed by me on my Form takes me to another instance for StudentID = 8131999, Form's Record No = 826 (count would be "3"), etc.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am aware you want to count records. The Allen Browne link is discussing counting records.

Your DCount() would have to be:

`DCount("*","[Depression Form Query]","StudentID=" & [StudentID] & " AND RecordID < " & [RecordID]) + 1`

Just realized the Allen Browne link doesn't really go into use of DCount for this, just barely mentions it to advise that it can be very slow. And it can be.

If you apply filter criteria to the query, the same filter criteria would have to be constructed within the DCount() WHERE argument.

A nested query to rank within grouping would be even more complicated than the examples in the link.

A form is just not a practical vehicle for this calc. Better would be to build a report using its Grouping & Sorting feature and textbox RunningSum property.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you Paul R. for your response.  I tried the 
DCount statement you provided; I had to add an "=" sign.  It counted all of that specific students records (the "Y" in an X of Y), +1 (i.e., 7).  
I am after the "X" of an X of Y records that changes (1, 2, 3...) as you click from one record to the next **for the same StudentID** .  I have tried making a report and dragged it into the Form.  The query for that report is what I posted above.  It generates 6 records (the correct "Y" in X of Y) for StudentID 8131999.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to include the unique ID field in the DCount criteria. See revised answer.

Comment: Hello again Paul R,  I tried your revised DCount statement.  When I run the query, it asks me to enter ID.  I have no field named ID, just StudentID and ST_ID. Thanks, Vance

Comment: You need a field in the table that can be used as an ordering criteria for each student group in the DCount. Maybe that would be RecordNo field but if not than an autonumber field named ID should serve. Revised the code again.

Comment: Hello Paul R,  Thank you for your continued efforts.  I tried your DCount statement but it would just return the number 1, regardless of record.

Comment: Hello Paul R,   I tried your DCount statement but it would just return the number 1, regardless of record.  I made an unbound field on a Report, set the Control Source to =1 and set Running Sum to Over All and it numbered the rows.   I dragged the Report into the Form's Design View.   It displayed all rows at once, which is OK as there should not be more than 10 rows.   Was really wanting it to just increment 1 record at a time so same textbox showed one, move to next record, 2, etc.  Thank you for your continued efforts.

Comment: Sorry the DCount() didn't work (it does for me). I would have to know more about your data structure. However, the report approach probably better anyway.

Comment: Hello Paul R,  Any chance you could send a small sample database to let me see how you made it work?  Thanks, Vancer

Comment: Rather you provide your effort for analysis. Post your query SQL statement or provide db. Can upload to a fileshare site such as Box.com and post link. I am not Paul R. See my name at end of comment.

Comment: Thank you June7.  I do not see a way to link or upload since I did so above.  My database now is fairly large, just in terms of structure.  Lots of database elements (tables, queries, forms, reports, a few modules).  I'm not really prone to use macros. Will study on a possible upload.  Didn't get that June7 was your forum name.  My bad V

Comment: Hello June7 and Paul R--used the DCount statement with a little revision:  =DCount("*","[Depression Form Query]","StudentID=" & [ST_ID] & " AND RecordNo < " & [RecordNo])+1.   This almost works perfectly except the RecordNo (you had RecordID which I didn't notice) is an autonumber.  Any deletions or late entries mess up the numerical order.  The TxDate field would solve this problem (sorted in Query) but it must require different syntax as it is a date.  It says error in the textbox on opening form when TxDate is substituted for RecordNo.   I am very encouraged.  A little more help please.

Comment: Sorry about typo on RecordNo. Use # delimiters, text field would use apostrophe `=DCount("*","[Depression Form Query]","StudentID=" & [ST_ID] & " AND TxDate < #" & [TxDate] & "#")+1`

Comment: This last statement worked a treat!  No need to apologize.  This has haunted me for over a week.  Now it's SOLVED thanks to you.  It still gives #Error in the textbox (Visit) when the form opens.  I made the field small enough so you only see ### until the user clicks or enters a StudentId and it calculates a number.  Thanks again, June7!!!